# How to simultaneously measure temperature at different depths?

Tags: sensor, temperature

EDITED - I need to simultaneously measure the temperature of water at ten depths. I only have a 10mm diameter access port set at 90 degrees which seems to suggest a 'flexible', cable like solution.

Water will be between 4 & 100 degs C. Depth is 1000 mm, and I want to measure every 100mm vertically. Accuracy needs to be approx. 1 degree.

"Can anyone suggest a potential way of electronically simultaneously measuring temperature at different depths"

Comment: Suggest you get a number of temperature sensors and mount them at different positions along a flexible cable. What depth resolution do you need? Analogue or digital? Is the fluid conductive or insulating, corrosive or benign? What accuracy do you need?

Comment: Easily done with fiber optics. (In fact, I spent decades making things like this.)

Comment: What's your measurement budget, YorkshireDave?

Comment: Neil. I did think of perhaps using NTC or PTC sensors but then reading them would need a multi channel reader of some description or a small processor along with its complications.

I also got to wonder if one is able to 'daisy chain' said sensors to reduce the number being read...

Comment: Jonk. I'm intrigued. This is simply a development for home at present. What would you estimate the potential costs to be? Just ballpark!

Comment: You've left out an important bit - how many sensors? And, in light of a previous comment, don't even think about using thermistors for this - the temperature range is too great. Also, you need to provide more details on what you're doing. Are you doing a vertical temp measurement as a 1 meter deep pot is brought to boiling? If it's just a tank of water just sitting there, I doubt you'll get much of a gradient, and I'd want sensors with better resolution. Finally, do you have experience building circuits with op amps, and if so, how much?

Comment: You're trying to measure the water temperature in a hot water heater as the water is used and it fills with cold water from the bottom, eh? There are multiple-junction T/C profile probes made however I don't think you'll like the price.

Comment: WhatRoughBeast. Want to measure every 100mm vertically. The 1 deg C resolution will be fine for my needs. Yes building ccts is no problem ;-)

Comment: As an alternative to the tomnexus answer, you might use one high-pin count micro, with 11 of 100K NTC, each at end of thin magnet wire twisted-pair. And they make very small NTC beads.

Answer (score 1):

For home temperature measurement projects it's hard to beat the DS18B20 sensor.

They're in a TO-92 package and you can have several on a 3 conductor "1-wire" bus, connected to your Arduino or raspberry pi. Factory calibrated to under 1°C and resolution of 0.0625°.

I've made stars and strings up to 7 devices but 10 or 20 should be fine. In your case you would solder 11 of them to three wires (or a long thin PCB), one every 10 cm, and protect the string with a *single* length of *glue lined* heatshrink. You might want to include a piece of steel wire or fibreglass rod to keep the string straight, otherwise it will curl up most infuriatingly.

A tiny bit of searching for  DS18B20 Arduino  or  DS18B20 Raspberry Pi  will find you hundreds of tutorials. Both support the sensor out of the box.

I feed mine to RRDTOOL to store and graph the temperatures over time, you can also get a cheap Arduino and have it print out the temperatures in text format.

They're not as cheap as thermistors but solve so many problems, for a one-off they're worth it. Stay away from the pre-wired "waterproof" sensors. They're not really waterproof, and the stainless steel tube thermally isolates the sensor inside, making it much slower to respond. Rather get the bare TO-92 and solder it yourself.

Comment: I like your answer, but at current prices of $3.41 each for 11,  that's $37.51 for just the DS18B20 chips. That compares to just one dollar USD for 11 x [NCU18WF104J60RB](https://digikey.com/en/products/detail/murata-electronics/NCU18WF104J60RB/9816018)   0603 surface-mount 100K NTC at Digikey.